# GCE kernel updates

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm running a Debian instance on GCE and want to prevent kernel updates as I don't want to have to reboot the instance unnecessarily.

I know that I can use `sudo apt-mark hold package_name` to stop kernel updates on the instance, but I don't know if it's safe to do this. For example, does using the above command on GCE instances have any unintended consequences, such as cascading dependencies, or causing issues with the parent server, for example when Google automatically moves an instance to a new zone for maintenance reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a problem with pinning or holding package versions during a live migration event since your virtual machine's settings are independent of the host/hypervisor it runs on. The state of the machine is preserved during a live migration down to the OS state and the state of its installed packages.

This post goes into detail what happens from a technical perspective: http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2015/03/Google-Compute-Engine-uses-Live-Migration-technology-to-service-infrastructure-without-application-downtime.html

Comment: Thank you. And thanks also for the link to the Google blog post, I hadn't seen that.